# Pricing PDE of Asian option by Shreve

Tags: option-pricing, brownian-motion, sde, asian-option, pde

I am currently working on "Stochastic Calculus for finance II, continuous time model" from Shreve. In chapter 7.5 Theo 7.5.1 he derives a pricing PDE with boundary conditions for an Asian call option and i do not understand his derivation of the first boundary condition. So we have
\begin{align*}
    dS_t=rS_tdt+S_tdW_t\\
    Y_t=\int_{0}^{t}S_udu\
\end{align*}
The boundary condtion is given by
\begin{align*}
    v(t,0,y)=e^{-r(T-t)}\max(\frac{y}{T}-K,0).
\end{align*}
His derivation:
"IF $S_t=0$ and $Y_t=y$ for some variable $t$, then $S_u=0, \ \forall u \in[t,T]$ and so $Y_u$ is constant on $[t,T]$ and therefore $Y_T=y$ and the value of the Asian call option at time t is $e^{-r(T-t)}\max(\frac{y}{T}-K,0)$".

**Problem:**
I do not understand why $S_t=0$ implies $S_u=0, \ \forall u \in[t,T]$.
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intuitively, once a stock hits value zero the underlying company is bankrupt and the value remains zero (this might not be true in the real world but it's a common assumption). So, once $S_t$ is zero it remains zero. Mathematically, if $S_t = 0$:

$$
\begin{align}
dS_t &= rS_tdt+S_tdW_t \\
&= r \times 0 \times dt + 0 \times dW_t \\
&= 0.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! i'm just wondering why the same argumentation for the boundary condition is used in this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.02523 , Theorem 14), even though in this case $S_t=(-a_1X_t+\gamma_t)dt+dW_t$. To my understanding, this process can again take on values unequal to zero, so after it was zero

Comment: I'd say that's material for a new question and a new answer.